# Show Web Info across different Site Collections

Tags: list, web-services, site-collection, iframe

I'd like to

1. Show List Info in `http://goSiteABC` from `http:goSiteXYZ;` 
   using webservice or Javascript Model if possible
2. Or Show an iFrame web page in `http://goSiteABC` from `http:goSiteXYZ`

The SharePoint instances are on the same server.

**What tools are available to make this happen? 

Before I start building content, Is this doable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint lists are surfaced as web services so you can use Javascript to call something like SPServices or REST to get the data from a remote list.

Comment: How do I do that without security issues?

Comment: There is a good discussion of when to use SPServices or COM at https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/when-to-choose-spservices-vs-the-client-side-object-model-csom.aspx including some comments about authentication.